# Vendor Asset Pipeline CSS in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I know there are 100's of resources on this but I have spent over 3 hours and just can't seem to figure this out. Everything is working locally but when I push to Heroku all hell breaks loose.

Here is my folder structure:

```
vendor
-assets
--custom
---impression
----css
-----file1.css
-----file2.css
-----file3.css
```

I have it called in my application.scss like this

```
@import "impression/css/animate.css";
@import "impression/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "impression/css/main.css";
@import "impression/css/responsive.css";
@import "impression/fonts/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "impression/fonts/simple-line-icons.css";
@import "impression/css/slicknav.css";
@import "impression/css/nivo-lightbox.css";
@import "impression/css/animate.css";
@import "impression/css/owl.carousel.css";
@import "impression/css/colors/default.css";
```

I have tried every combination of moving things in and out of the different subdirectories of vendor locally but each time when I push to production it shows 404's for the files.

The weird part is all the js assets are compiling find and showing up. They are in the file structure like this

```
vendor
-assets
--custom
---impression
----js
-----file1.js
-----file2.js
-----file3.js
```

And are called in application.js like so

```
//= require impression/js/bootstrap.min.js
//= require impression/js/jquery.countdown.min.js
//= require impression/js/smooth-scroll.js
//= require impression/js/wow.js
//= require impression/js/owl.carousel.min.js
//= require impression/js/jquery.slicknav.js
//= require impression/js/nivo-lightbox.js
//= require impression/js/form-validator.min.js
//= require impression/js/contact-form-script.js
//= require impression/js/main.js
```

I tried having it precompile assets during the build on heroku and it seemed to work but it would get so far and fail because it was precompiling some gem files assets too and they were breaking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your application asset files folder structure are not correct. I modified your folder structure and you can try and check.

Here is the modified folder structure:

```
vendor
-assets
--stylesheets
---custom
----impression
-----file1.css
-----file2.css
-----file3.css
```

Here's your application.scss file

```
@import "custom/impression/animate";
@import "custom/impression/bootstrap.min";
@import "custom/impression/main";
@import "custom/impression/responsive";
@import "custom/impression/font-awesome.min";
@import "custom/impression/simple-line-icons";
@import "custom/impression/slicknav";
@import "custom/impression/nivo-lightbox";
@import "custom/impression/animate";
@import "custom/impression/owl.carousel";
@import "custom/impression/colors/default";
```

Here's JS modified folder structure

```
vendor
-assets
--javascripts
---custom
----impression
-----file1.js
-----file2.js
-----file3.js
```

And are called in application.js like so

```
//= require custom/impression/bootstrap.min
//= require custom/impression/jquery.countdown.min
//= require custom/impression/smooth-scroll
//= require custom/impression/wow
//= require custom/impression/owl.carousel.min
//= require custom/impression/jquery.slicknav
//= require custom/impression/nivo-lightbox
//= require custom/impression/form-validator.min
//= require custom/impression/contact-form-script
//= require custom/impression/main
```

I hope it should work.

Comment: Also if you need any font's display error issue, you can check this answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047545/rails-5-1-2-bootstrap-icons-not-being-served-in-production/48052602#48052602