# How to install local fonts for rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am trying to add a font to my Rails 5.1 project, however, it seems the project can't find the font. Here is the directory for the fonts:

```
app
├── assets
│   ├── config
│   │   └── manifest.js
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── Open-Sans.eot
│   │   ├── Open-Sans.svg
│   │   ├── Open-Sans.ttf
│   │   └── Open-Sans.woff
```

In my `application.rb` I do added the fonts path:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

Here is my `base.scss` file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open-Sans";
  src: asset-url('Open-Sans.ttf') format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  // font-family: $body-font-family;
  // background-color: #2f4050;
  background-color: #222;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: $text-color;
  overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

I am not sure what is wrong... any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in the console and update the question with the output?

Comment: You can follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047545/rails-5-1-2-bootstrap-icons-not-being-served-in-production/48052602#48052602 , Hope it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have to modify the base.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open-Sans";
  src: url(asset-path('Open-Sans.ttf')) format("truetype");
}

body {
  font-family: "Open-Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  // font-family: $body-font-family;
  // background-color: #2f4050;
  background-color: #222;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: $text-color;
  overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

After this change, You have to restart your web server.

Comment: I tried, now I can see the change in the development environment. But the font is still not showing up in the production environment. Is this related to Nginx?

Comment: Turns out the solution works with www.mysite.com; but mysite.com has some CORS problem.